# 'Next privilege' design bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

The background color in `Next Privilege` is not completely filled. Here is a screenshot to explain it:

[image]

Comment: Apparently the progress bar's border is stretching to the bottom, and since your "Measure your impact" still has the default message (which is longer than when it's filled), the border gets stretched...

Comment: If you write question or make an answer, that space will be filled with top tag info so it won't glitch.

Comment: Post on meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313525/ This shows up on sites joined after SE changed the borders around the trackers.

Comment: This will be solved with the new responsive design that's being rolled out Stack Exchange-wide.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed.

Comment: @Chair Yes. It if fixed but I think its in beta testing. Please post an answer.

Comment: @BlackThunder I don't have enough details for an answer. I've flagged my post on the main meta, requesting the 'status-completed' tag, but there has been no response until now. Perhaps once the SE team looks at that, they'll leave a message about what the issue was and when it was fixed, after which I could put a notice here. I'll also flag this post for mod attention asking for the status-completed tag.

Comment: Bam! Tim Post just added the status-completed tag to the main meta post (meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313525).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed with the new responsive design.

Comment: Actually, I'm inclined to believe that this isn't directly related to the responsive design: it's fixed even on sites with the old themes, and the fix seems to have happened at the same time dozens of other things on the profile page broke (look at the bug tag on meta SE)